# Pull data from RESTful server to SQL

Tags: sql, api, rest

Recently, I have a solution but I am not sure whether it works or not. So the problem is:
I have a RESTful API, this RESTful server which is operating by others contains the data that we want to get. After retrieve the data, I want to use SQL database store this data in my server.

How can I implement it? Please give me some advice.

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what your application does? After importing data into SQL database what you like to do?

Comment: Thank you for focuing on my question. The purpose is data analysis. Basically, I didn't make the application. Because I focus on the data, I just need to query from RESTful server then store in my database. then I can do research via my database.

Comment: you will have to write a script to do this. The script will query your api, get the data and make insert statements to put it in a db

Comment: What type of analysis? Using some kind of reporting tools or executing SQL query? What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks Somesh, yes, I am planing to use java to call RESTful. But the return is Json, I didn't figure out how to put in database. I installed mysql, but if other databases work for it well, I prefer the best solution.

Comment: Hi Shamim, Actually, it's my paper research. SQL query and get conclusion. The challenge is this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following and I'm considering you will use java as a programming language

1. Create a new database structure (tables). For example in  MySQL
   database.
2. Use jdbc to connect your database.
3. Use Apache HTTP client or Spring RestTemplate library to consume the
   data from Rest API and insert into your database table